# how to mapping a field type in "Feeds module "?

Tags: feeds

[image]
[image]

1. In the first picture.
   This "Pinboard helper module element" field type(the 1th red circle ) is make by a module .
2. The second picture is [Feeds](https://www.drupal.org/project/feeds) module . This field type can not show in the "TARGET menu".
   (the 2th red circle )

Question:

How can make this field type(the 1th red circle ) show in the feeds Target(the 2th red circle ) ? 
must write a module to use the "Pinboard" fields?

Comment: I reopened this.  Can you make the first screenshot a bit bigger so we can see it better?  We don't need anything to the left of the **Field Type** column.  Also, what module is providing this field type?

Comment: very thank for ur kind answer.that is come from a drupal theme name "drupal pinboard  [version v1.1.2]"

Comment: i am trying to make the picture bigger but seem do not work.but i can see the bigger image by the address :http://i.stack.imgur.com/ZhiTc.jpg

Comment: and i can give the whole theme file to you. can you help me ? very very thank u for you kind . hopes you good everyday.

Comment: I had the same problem when I added a type of field, which is Field collections, created by the module Field collection. It did not appear in the list in the importer feed, so I had to install Field Collection Feeds module. I am afraid that if a module does not exist that imports that kind of data, you will have to create your own module. Search a little in Drupal org.

Comment: Try this module. It is different from Feeds but it may be more versatile. I hope it helps you.

Comment: For God's sake, this question has been floating around by 2 years now, and still being edited and then promoted to the first page of listing. Damn it.